# Excel -- Cell Values Match in First Row, Return Values on One Row with Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2013, worksheet-function

### Here's an explanation of what I'm having difficulty with:

Column A: Lists the Address Book Numbers for different companies (1234, 1235, 1236, etc.)

Column B: Lists the Phone Types (Cell, Fax, Home)

Column C: Lists Company Phone Numbers

> **Address Book Numbers** from **Column A** are repeated in multiple rows (due to the fact that some companies have more than one **Phone Number** in **Column C**)... So, I'm looking to consolidate the **Address Book Numbers** that are the same (to one row) and have each phone number pertaining to the same address number in additional columns (within that row).

---

Current Excel Table:

---

```
AddressBookNumber  PhoneType  PhoneNumber
1234               CELL       (444)444-4444
1235               FAX        (777)777-7777
1234               OFFICE     (000)000-0000
1236               FAX        (222)222-2222
1234               HOME       (555)555-5555
1236               OFFICE     (111)111-1111
```

---

Would like my Excel Table to look like:

```
|AddressBookNumber | PhoneType1 | PhoneNumber1  | Phone Type2 | PhoneNumber2  | PhoneType3 | PhoneNumber3  |
|1234              |CELL        | (444)444-4444 | OFFICE      | (000)000-0000 | HOME       | (555)555-5555 |
|1235              |FAX         | (777)777-7777 |             |               |            |
|1236              |FAX         | (222)222-2222 | OFFICE      | (111)111-1111 |            |
```

---

Essentially, I need to have the phone numbers pertaining to one company all in one row.. would appreciate any assistance on the formula I should use. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a formula you can use. you need to write some code in VBA

Comment: Use countif to create a unique number for each company and concatenate it with the addressbooknumber and than index match the numbers into the field.

Comment: I agree with @user3666237.

Comment: I have 766 unique 'addressbooknumbers' (and 961 total before I remove the duplicate values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the unique list use this array formula put this in F2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$7),0)),"")
```

Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter on exit of edit mode instead of Enter.  Then copy/drag down till you get blanks.

And to get the numbers put this in G2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$7,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,$B$2:$B$7,$F$2:F2,$C$2:$C$7)=0)*($A$2:$A$7=$F2),0),MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,2)+1),"")
```

Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter on exit of edit mode instead of Enter.  Then copy/drag down and over till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott! I got column F to work using your first formula. However, when I use the second formula in column G, all I am getting are blanks. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Nope,  did you put the formula in the formula bar then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  Did Excel put the `{}` around the formula?  This is the only thing I can think of that would return errors. @BK.42

Comment: @BK.42 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: One last thing: I've never used the MOD function before in Excel, can you explain what the "-1,2)+1),"")" mean? I'm hoping to apply this knowledge to future spreadsheets. Thanks!

Comment: Mod returns the remainder after doing the division.  Column(A:A) is a counter that increases as the formula is dragged across.  The -1 starts it at 0 so the first column would return the remainder of 0/2 which is 0 then add 1.  the next column would return the remainder of 1/2 which is 1 and add 1 so it will be 2.  In short it makes a pattern of 1,2,1,2,... as it is dragged across.